# Automating instagram sign up with python requests

Tags: python, automation, http-post, python-requests, instagram

I am fairly new to using requests and python, and I'm just trying to test the waters.I am simply trying to automate the sign up form on www.instagram.com. I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here are the request headers:
https://gyazo.com/032e97dbcd72f5d782488ad252919758?token=c15f8644eb1f0e40b001f50995d74c23

Here is the form data:
https://gyazo.com/53a154adc0c16ba17f4f9199949cb465

Lastly, this is the code I have so far:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com'

    EMAIL = 'testafhsdfh38@gmail.com'
    PASSWORD = 'testpass1234' 
    USERNAME = 'blsdh37fgtest'
    NAME = 'Jon Doe'


    c.get(url)
    csrftoken = c.cookies['csrftoken']

    login_data = dict(csrftoken=csrftoken, email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD, username=USERNAME, fisrt_name=NAME, seamless_login_enabled=1)
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "https://www.instagram.com"})
    page = c.get('https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en#registered')
```

Comment: Doesn't instagram use captcha or something during signup?

Comment: Nope, there is no captcha when signing up a new account.

Comment: Thats....interesting. Have you checked to see what the requests look like when you do it from a browser?

Comment: Checking as in checking the network tab when inspecting the page source? Yes.

Comment: I assume the cookie is pretty important, so you may have to use sessions to get the cookie and then post.

Comment: Mind elaborating on using "sessions to get the cookie and then post" ?

Comment: This explains better than i can http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: With many thanks to SuperStew - I can now comment! OP : I can advise two main things : 1. Simulate the POST request with Firefox or any browser/extension(like postman) that lets you send a post request. 2. Check for the response coming from the server, print it and its status code, perhaps you can find some useful information there. Perhaps we can understand the problem better this way.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot add a comment (less than 50), but from what I see, you're not sending the POST request to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/, but for http://www.instagram.com which can probably be an issue since Instagram's / url route does not know what to do with your POST request's data. There could be other issues, but that's what I'm spotting at first.

Again - this is better suited for a comment, but I wanted to help and I cannot comment until I'm atleast +50 rep.

Comment: Gave this ago, but still no account is being created.